# Определение кол-ва записей с лимитом, найденных по запросу SQL (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, pagination

Хочу делать запрос в базу данных MySQL, мне нужно получить только 5 записей из неё, но при этом мне необходимо сосчитать общее количество записей, удовлетворяющих моему условию.

То есть мне надо по строке запросе пользователя вывести ему на 1 страницу только 5 записей, но кол-во страниц придётся считать от общего количества найденных записей.

Я понимаю, что можно сделать запрос без лимита, но тогда мне вернется слишком много данных, а если делать 2 запроса: 1 получает кол-во записей, а второй получает 5 записей, то придётся 2 раза присоединяться к бд и тратить дополнительное время на поиск заново.

Вопрос, можно ли как-то это сделать в 1 SQL запросе или минимизировать затраты ресурсов при 2-х запросах. Поправьте, если что-то не так понимаю.

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888696/5506820)

Это возможно сделать при помощи ***[оконных функций](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)***, но в MySql их ввели только с 8-й версии (см. [статью](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/) или [cюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199638/5506820)).
Вот пример использования:

```
create table test (
id integer,
field integer  
);

insert into test (id, field) values (1,10);
insert into test (id, field) values (2,10);
insert into test (id, field) values (3,10);
insert into test (id, field) values (5,20);

SELECT id 
, count(*) OVER() AS full_count 
FROM   test
WHERE  field=10
LIMIT  2;
```

И [наглядный результат работы](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e9866) (но для postgress, т.к. указанный ресурс даёт возможность потестировать только запрос для MySql 5.6)

[image: Результат тестирования на Postgresql]

P.S. Единственный момент, что у тебя в каждой записи будет общее количество записей из выборки. Но я не думаю, что это будет какой-то весомой проблемой)

Comment: Спасибо, это как раз то, что я искал

Comment: @ЕльцовДанил, в таком случае отметьте ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 3):

Копайте в сторону SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as
(select * from t where ...)
select *, (select count(*) from cte)  qty  from cte limit 5
;
```

Comment: Автор в тексте указывает, что речь идёт про MySQL, но не указывает версию. Так что в общем случае следует считать, что cte недоступны.

Comment: @Akina, без cte переписать не проблема. Так ведь?

Comment: Формально - да. Но зачем? когда есть штатные средства, указанные товарищами **JVic** и **MAX**.

Comment: Автор просил сделать в одном запросе. Я ответил.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо создать скроллируемый `Statement`, по умолчанию `ResultSet` может двигаться только вперед, то есть если вы попробуете посчитать количество возвращенных строк, то обратно не сможете вернуться. Надо сделать что-то типа:

```
//скроллируемый указатель только для чтения
stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
               ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + dbName);
rs.last(); //двигаем указатель на последнюю запись
int recs=rs.getRow(); //получаем количество записей
rs.beforeFirst(); //двигаем курсор перед первой записью
while (rs.next()) {
    //работаем с записями
}
```

Answer (score 2):

хорошие ответы уже были, но позвольте и мне тоже что то сказать :)
и так:

1. можете смотреть вот [->сюда<-](https://habr.com/post/64655/) вроде как есть на ваш вопрос ответ
2. можете просто получить все записи и на уровне языка получить и нужные 5 записей и общее количество в бд. типа так

   `resultList.size() //дает общее количество
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(mc.toString());
   }`
3. можете воспользоваться с процедурой, только в этом случае вам придется писать два резалтсета

   `CREATE DEFINER = 'test'@'%'
   PROCEDURE test.procedure1 ()
   BEGIN
     SELECT
       COUNT(t.id) AS count
     FROM table m;
     SELECT
       t.id,
       t.state,
       t.name
     FROM table t
     LIMIT 5;
   END`